# SocketServer continue execution after serve_forever

Tags: python

I'm using the SocketServer module in python to implement a simple embedded web server in my application. At the moment I'm calling the serve_forver method within a dedicated thread in order to continue the execution of my application.

I was wondering if there is there a more pythonic way to start my SocketServer and retun the execution to my application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a very pythonic way:

```
threading.Thread(target=myServer.serve_forever).start()
```

I don't see how that could be unclear or overly verbose. If you want the program to exit once your main thread finishes, add `daemon=True` to the `Thread` call.

An alternative is calling [`handle_request`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.handle_request) in a loop yourself, but that doesn't seem applicable to your case of a web-server.